# Can Menu and onKeyDown work together?

Tags: android

I want to use `Menu` and `OnkeyDown`  in same activity but it is not working, when I use `OnkeyDown` then menu disappear from the activity. I want to make a action using virtual keyboard's enter key. When I press enter key of virtual keyboard one toast should be appear.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return false outside the switch statement of the onKeyDown but true for every key you handle:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int KeyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     switch (KeyCode) {
     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
        //take photo
        return true;
     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
        //lower volume
        return true;
     case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
        //raise volume
        return true;
     }
    return false;
    }
```

This works for 2.3.3